# Add emojis to input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, emoji

I am building a chat and I am using a library called `emoji-picker-react` and I want to add emojis to my text field and then send it as a message. I am using react so I will simplified the code for convinience.
My messages are working but my emojis not so much.
So far, if I click the emojis first and follow with some text, is fine.
But if I type first and I try to add the emojis it won't work.
Also, if I try to send emojis on its own, it won't work either.
This is what I used to add emojis on my text field and both do the same.

This is where I try to add the emojis into my text field and is doing what I just explained:

```
const onEmojiClick = (e, emojiObject) => {
document.querySelector("#text").value += emojiObject.emoji
  // document.getElementById("text").value += emojiObject.emoji
};
```

And this is my input field:

```
<input
 id="text"
 style={inputStyles}
 type="text"
 placeholder="Type your message"
 value={message}
 onKeyPress={e => {
  if (e.key !== 'Enter') return;
    sendMessage(message);
  }
 }
 onChange={e => setMessageForm(e.target.value)}
/>
```

I am sure is something simple but can't get my head around it. I hope someone can guide on this.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the html part where you call onEmojiClick function?

Comment: Rather than bypassing react by trying to maipulate the value of the input element directly you should append the selected emoji to the `message` state. react will update the value of the input for you. Generally speking you never need to manually query any DOM elements that are managed by react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a reference to the `input` node to get the cursor position and update the message value:

```
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const onEmojiClick = (event, emojiObject) => {
    const cursor = ref.current.selectionStart;
    const text = message.slice(0, cursor) + emojiObject.emoji + message.slice(cursor);
    setMessageForm(text);
  };
```

jsx

```
<input
  id="text"
  ref={ref}
  ...
/>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gg2akb?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 6):

A little update to @lissettdm's answer.

##### Common issue when inserting emojis.

after inserting emoji, the cursor will move to the end of the line.

##### Improved answer

The cursor stays where the emoji is so the user can input multiple emojis.

```
 const ref = useRef(null);
  const onEmojiClick = (event, emojiObject) => {
    const cursor = ref.current.selectionStart;
    
    const text = message.slice(0, cursor) + emojiObject.emoji + message.slice(cursor);
    setMessageForm(text);
    
    //Codes added for the new cursor
    const newCursor = cursor+emojiObject.emoji.length
    setTimeout(() => ref.current.setSelectionRange(newCursor,newCursor), 10)
  };
```

##### Code explanation

Depending on what emoji package you use, `emojiObject.emoji` may be unified, native or id. The **common mistake and biggest mistake** is to presume 1 emoji = 1 character (cursor+1), which is not the case.

For example if you are using emoji-mart, and you use emoji.native, the length is 2 ( not 1 ).

```
const newCursor = cusor+emojiObject.emoji.length
```

The following set the new cursor position to be **after the emoji**. Why the timeout? It's to allow `setMessage(text)` ample time to update the dom with the new value, before you use the ref to set cursor.

If you do not use `setTimeout`, the cursor may not be updated correctly.

```
setTimeout(() => ref.current.setSelectionRange(newCursor,newCursor), 10)
```

Comment: To improve your answer even more: Get selectionEnd and use this in your second slice. With this you can also mark text and replace your selection. (Like expected)

Comment: adding a `ref.current.focus();` after setTimeout will enable user to type and pick emojies at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly setting the `value` of your text input won't trigger an `onChange` event. Include the Emoji Picker in the component that holds the input's state and call it's setter (assuming you use functional components, call `this.setState` otherwise) when an Emoji is picked, appending it to the current state.

You may want to read the cursor position using a `ref` on the input element and its `selectionStart` property to insert the emoji there.

for example, you could write your input component like this

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'
import /* your EmojiPicker component */

const InputWithEmojiPicker = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const inputRef = useRef(null)
  
  const onEmojiClick = (e, emojiObject) => {
    const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = inputRef.current
    // replace selected text with clicked emoji
    const newVal = value.slice(0, selectionStart) + emojiObject.emoji + value.slice(selectionEnd)
    setValue(newValue)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} value={value} onChange={setValue} />
      {/* your EmojiPicker component with onEmojiClick */}
    </div>
  )
}

export default InputWithEmojiPicker
```

Comment: This also works! I am still learning react an hooks so I would never thought of that!

Comment: The important thing to remember here is to avoid directly accessing DOM elements to explicitly set their attributes. Use State wherever you can and let React fill in the values.

Comment: Sure, I knew that I was doing something wrong when trying to use plain js on react. This is a tech test, so I hope i get the job for the junior position! Thank you :D

Comment: Heh, that reminds me of when I learned Vue over night to get an interview once. Good luck.